# Binding RibbonButton

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm playing with my first wpf project using the mvvm pattern.
I have Microsoft Ribbon for WPF, that i can't get to fire my method in the MainWindowViewModel.
I'm trying to follow as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button1" LargeImageSource="Images\home32.png" Label="Opret klub" Command="{Binding Path=CreateNewClub1}" />
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public RelayCommand CreateNewClub1()
    {
        return new RelayCommand(param => this.CreateNewClub());
    }
```

I can't get it to fire the method CreateNewClub1(). What am i missing?

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors (in the output subwindow in Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateNewClub1 must be a property, not a method:

```
public RelayCommand CreateNewClub1
{
    get
    { 
        return new RelayCommand(param => this.CreateNewClub()); 
    }
}
```